# Scala IDE: change in build.sbt does not affect my project compiling

Tags: scala, sbt, slf4j

I have a new sbt project. Once I add the following dependency in the build.sbt file:

```
"org.slf4j" %% "slf4j-log4j12" % "1.7.12",
```

When I compile the project, an error was produced as follow:

```
UNSOLVED DEPENDENCIES
org.slf4j#slf4j-log4j12_2.10;1.7.12 not found
```

So I just comment this line in my build.sbt file. The problem is that now when I compile the project the same error is produced. I also did Clean, Update, Compile, but I still have the same error.

How can I force the project to do the compile according to my new build.sbt and ignore the slf4j dependency??

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The command you're looking for is `reload`.

Answer (score 4):

I've recommend you to add dependency without extra **%**

```
libraryDependencies += "org.slf4j" % "slf4j-log4j12" % "1.7.12"
```

Two signd of percent said to **sbt**, that you want version of artifact created specifically for your version of Scala - you could see it in error message: it asking for **slf4j-log4j12_2.10**, where _2.10 is your Scala version

Comment: Thanks. Actually I was looking for Chris Martin response. But it help me to have SLF4J as a dependency. I just remove it because I couldn't figure it out how I add it without error.